# Moq Assert that object has not changed

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

If I have the code

```
public Response Foo(Request request)
{
    return _someObject.Bar(request);
}
```

I can mock `_someObject` and I want to assert that the object has not changed before being returned.  e.g.:

```
public Response Foo(Request request)
{
    var response = _someObject.Bar(request);
    return response.SomeProperty.SomeOtherProperty + 1;
}
```

I know I can walk through every member on the DTO, but that's allot of typing for any DTO of any real size or depth.

Is hashing the objects the best solution, or is there a better why?

Comment: Can you mock the DTO, `Request`?

Comment: I suppose...  That would mean adding interfaces to the DTOs as well.  I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to checking all the values on a DTO might be to create a strict mock for it, and pass that instead. E.g.

```
var mockRequest = new Mock<IRequest>(MockBehavior.Strict);
```

Set up expectations for any property gets as usual, and then leave it to Moq to fail your tests if there are any unexpected property sets on the mock DTO.

Comment: I think that might be the best solution... still don't like having to put interfaces on my DTOs... but I'm not sure why I don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to compare that the object before and after the call are equal by using any assertion framework that allows you to compare two objects. If the method returns the same object type, then you can use the returned object to compare it to the original. Otherwise, you can use a callback, if using Moq, to get the object used by the dependency

```
[Test]
public void Foo_WhenCallingFoo_ShouldNotAlterTheRequest()
{
      var request = new Request();

      var result = Foo(Request);

      result.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(requests);
}
```

Or if method under tests returns a different type, you can use Callback to get the object that was passed to the dependency and compare to that:

```
// Arrange
Request requestUsedBySomeObject = null;
var originalRequest = new Request();
var someObject = new Mock<SomeObject>();
someObject.Setup(s => s.Bar(It.IsAny<Request>()).Callback<Request>(r => requestUsedBySomeObject = r ));

// Act
Foo(originalRequest );

// Assert
originalRequest .ShouldBeEquivalentTo(requestUsedBySomeObject);
```